# Recording speed javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, video, recording

I am currently creating a project that supports video recording through my website.

I create a canvas and then push the recorded frames to it. The problem is, when I play the video after its recorded, it plays too fast. A 10 second long video plays in like 2 seconds. I have checked the playbackRate is set to 1. I save the recording to a database and its speeded up there aswell, so it has nothing to do with the browsers videoplayer.

I am relative new to AngularJS and javascript so im sorry if I left something important out.

I have tried changing alot of the values back and forth but I cant seem to find the cause for the problem. Any ideas?

Here is the code for the video recording:

```
scope.startRecording = function () {
            if (mediaStream) {
                var video = $('.video-capture')[0];
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
                canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width;
                var CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height;

                function drawVideoFrame(time) {
                    videoRecorder = requestAnimationFrame(drawVideoFrame);
                    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
                    recordedFrames.push(canvas.toDataURL('image/webp', 1));
                }

                videoRecorder = requestAnimationFrame(drawVideoFrame); // Note: not using vendor prefixes!
                scope.recording = true;
            }

        };
        scope.stopRecording = function () {
            cancelAnimationFrame(videoRecorder);  // Note: not using vendor prefixes!

            // 2nd param: framerate for the video file.
            scope.video.files = Whammy.fromImageArray(recordedFrames, 1000 / 30);
            recordedVideoBlob = Whammy.fromImageArray(recordedFrames, 1000 / 30);
            scope.videoMode = 'viewRecording';
            scope.recording = false;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guess the culprit is `requestAnimationFrame`, left on it's own, you cannot tell at what intervals it keeps calling the callback, it can be as high as 60fps.

also looking at your code, I cannot tell how you came to the conclusion that frame rate = `1000/30`

my advice( at least for your case) would be to go with [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval), 
you can do something like:

```
scope.frameRate = 10, videoInterval;    // the amount I consider ideal for client-side video recording.

scope.startRecording = function () {
    if (mediaStream) {
        var video = $('.video-capture')[0];
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width;
        var CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height;

        function drawVideoFrame() {
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
            recordedFrames.push(canvas.toDataURL('image/webp', 1));
        }
        videoInterval = $interval(drawVideoFrame, 1000/scope.frameRate);
        scope.recording = true;
    }
};

scope.stopRecording = function () {
     $interval.cancel(videoInterval);  

    // 2nd param: framerate for the video file.
    scope.video.files = Whammy.fromImageArray(recordedFrames, scope.frameRate);
    recordedVideoBlob = Whammy.fromImageArray(recordedFrames, scope.frameRate);   // you can chage this to some file copy method, so leave out the duplicate processing of images into video.
    scope.videoMode = 'viewRecording';
    scope.recording = false;
};
```